# Cancel/suppress bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap, and when I try to make a simple `<ul>` and `<li>` I can see that bootstrap automatically applies some effects to it. Is it possible to suppress/cancel bootstrap css if it's inside a div?

```
<div class="somename">
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can override the bootstrap CSS.But to be clear please post some code you are working

Comment: added a basic example

Comment: wherever you don't require the bootstrap style, use your custom css class and include for your `li` or `ul`